# How to add/modify events in Google calendar with ICS file

Tags: email, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to create an ICS file to add events to a Google calendar via email. In the end, the calendar will be sent to multiple users, from a desktop app. Ideally I'd like to be able to modify the calendar if the events change (just event times, I'm ignoring cancelled events)

Here is my ICS file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//MY COMPANY//Calendar//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:shift-439-emp-128@mycompany.com
DTSTART:20180604T090000
DTEND:20180604T153000
DTSTAMP:20180519T081800
SUMMARY:Morning shfit
LOCATION:Morning Location
DESCRIPTION:Morning shift
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:shift-446-emp-128@mycompany.com
DTSTART:20180605T153000
DTEND:20180605T233000
DTSTAMP:20180519T081800
SUMMARY:Night shift
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:Night
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I email that file to my gmail account, I can see a "Add to Google calendar" button which I can use to add the events to my prinary calendar.

Now, say the events times changed.

**Question** : How can I create a new ICS file with the new times so that existing events will be modified in google calendar?

I used UIDs for events so that google does not create duplicate entries. But when I email a second ics file with modified events (with uids), the "add to google calendar" button does not appear. If I try to manually import the ics file from google calendar Import feature, then I get this error message

> Could not upload your events because you do not have sufficient access on the target calendar.

If I set different UIDs each time, the import process will work but duplicate entries will be created.

I also tried using `REQUEST` instead of `PUBLISH` method

Thanks

Comment: if you want this kind of control you'd be better interacting with the calendar data programmatically via the API, rather than relying on the email interface. https://developers.google.com/calendar/

Comment: Yes but to add/modify events to the calendar for other users, I'd need their API key. For now, the email is sent to a desktop app

Comment: ah ok. You only mentioned emailing your own gmail account. Maybe in that case you're better off providing an ICS feed at a URL, which others can subscribe to. That way the syncing is handled by their own calendar software. I don't know, it depends on your overall requirements, which I don't know enough about. Either way, I don't believe you can achieve this by emailing static ics files around.

Comment: For ability to update, import is no good -  just adds event data to an existing calendar, which user can overwrite - this i not usually helpful if there is a potential for updates .'Subscribed' url is better - appear in the receiving application as a separate calendar.and will eventually update. Then you must have the same UID for the events and a SEQUENCE to indicate which is the latest update of that event.  If you are modifying an instance of a recurring event, you would also need a RECURRENCE-ID to indicate which instance you are modifying.  Google RFC5545 and SEQUENCE

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I'll investigate ICS feeds

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this working with Gmail using the following:

- `METHOD`: set to `REQUEST`
- `SEQUENCE`: Set to `0` on first request and increment by 1 each time
- `ATTENDEE`: Identify the Gmail user that is receiving the email by email address

Other variations would have non-desirable effects:

- Only seeing 1 of the two events
- Not updating existing event

Office 365 sends ICS files to Gmail that can be updated so it can be used to reference a commercial implementation. You can see the requests Outlook 365 sends by using "Show Original" in Gmail to retrieve the base64 encoded calendar body. Outlook 365 uses many other fields so it's instructive to examine.

I have a test script in Go using SparkPost so if you have any questions or would like to use it, just let me know. SparkPost has a free tier but you still need to configure your outbound sending domain to use it.

Here is an example modified request. I just increment the `SEQUENCE` and change the time to update the request in Gmail.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//MY COMPANY//Calendar//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=example@gmail.com:MAILTO:example@gmail.com
UID:shift-1807-emp-128@mycompany.com
DTSTART:20180807T010000
DTEND:20180807T020000
DTSTAMP:20180601T033455
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Morning shift
LOCATION:Morning Location
DESCRIPTION:Morning shift
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=example@gmail.com:MAILTO:example@gmail.com
UID:shift-1808-emp-128@mycompany.com
DTSTART:20180807T130000
DTEND:20180807T140000
DTSTAMP:20180601T033455
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Night shift
LOCATION:Night Location
DESCRIPTION:Night
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Of note, when sending multiple events in a single ICS file, sometimes it takes Gmail a second or so to show both events with the correct time in my testing.

Comment: Thank, I'll try that. I'm not sure it'll be working, but my bounty was going to expire I prefered awarding it to you rather than wasting it. I'll accept the answer if it works

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I have a working example and will look to post the code, and possibly a video, later.

Comment: I posted a working example here: https://github.com/grokify/oauth2more/blob/master/sparkpost/examples/send_ics/main.go . This posts two shifts as in your example and can change both shifts by incrementing the `seq` sequence number and the times (manually change the hour).

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look and let you know in a few days hopefully